# Binding MenuItem in UserControl to collapse frame in Mainwindow

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm somewhat new to WPF databinding so bear with me. The behavior I want is to bind a MenuItem in a UserControl and use this to collapse a frame in MainWindow. I'm using and booltoVisibility converter to help with the type conversion. When I run the code the frame doesn't collapse. In the output window I get the error "Cannot save value from target back to source... System Argument exception: "True" is not a valid value for Property CollapseFrame". I think it may have something to do with how I constructed the dependency property but I can't quite figure it out.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestBooleanToVisibilityConverter.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestBooleanToVisibilityConverter"
    xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    Title="MainWindow"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

<Grid Margin="30">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisibleOrHidden x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" Collapse="True" Reverse="True" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Frame 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.Row="0"
        MinWidth= "200"
        MinHeight= "20"
        BorderBrush="Gray"
        BorderThickness="3"
        Visibility="{Binding FrameIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" >
    </Frame>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <local1:Menu
        CollapseFrame="{Binding FrameIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" >
        </local1:Menu>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using System.Windows;  
using System.Windows.Controls;  
using System.Windows.Data;  
using System.Windows.Documents;  
using System.Windows.Input;  
using System.Windows.Media;  
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;  
using System.Windows.Navigation;  
using System.Windows.Shapes;  
using WpfApp1;  

namespace TestBooleanToVisibilityConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FrameIsVisible = false;
        }

        public bool FrameIsVisible { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Menu.xaml

```
    <UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.Menu"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             x:Name="myUserControl"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Menu >
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem x:Name="HideFrame" Header="Hide Frame" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=CollapseFrame}"  />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</UserControl>
```

Menu.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Menu.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Menu : UserControl
    {
        public Menu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CollapseFrameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CollapseFrame",
            typeof(Visibility),
            typeof(Menu),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));

        public Visibility CollapseFrame
        {
            get { return (Visibility)GetValue(CollapseFrameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CollapseFrameProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

BooleanToVisibleOrHidden.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestBooleanToVisibilityConverter {
    class BoolToVisibleOrHidden : IValueConverter
    {
        #region Constructors

        public BoolToVisibleOrHidden() { }
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public bool Collapse { get; set; }
        public bool Reverse { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region IValueConverter Members
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool bValue = (bool)value;

            if (bValue != Reverse)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Collapse)
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
                else
                    return Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;

            if (visibility == Visibility.Visible)
                return !Reverse;
            else
                return Reverse;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a converter that converts from a `Visibility` to a `Boolean`:

```
public class VisibleOrHiddenToBool : IValueConverter
{
    #region Properties
    public bool Collapse { get; set; }
    public bool Reverse { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region IValueConverter Members
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility visibility = (Visibility)value;

        if (visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            return !Reverse;
        else
            return Reverse;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool bValue = (bool)value;

        if (bValue != Reverse)
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Collapse)
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            else
                return Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Menu.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:VisibleOrHiddenToBool x:Key="converter" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Menu >
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem x:Name="HideFrame" Header="Hide Frame" IsCheckable="True" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=CollapseFrame, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"  />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

You should then set the binding to the `FrameIsVisible` property in the window to `TwoWay`:

```
<local:Menu x:Name="menu" CollapseFrame="{Binding FrameIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Finally, you also need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise `PropertyChanged` notifications in the window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool _frameIsVisible;
    public bool FrameIsVisible
    {
        get { return _frameIsVisible; }
        set { _frameIsVisible = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! works now. What throws me off is that the problem seems like it is OneWay binding and not TwoWay. How is this explained? Is it because the state of the frame determines whether the menuitem is checked or not? Also, it seems that embedding my entire menu structure in a usercontrol instead of having it reside in the mainwindow adds a fair amount of overhead and additional complexity. Maybe it is not worth trying to separate the menu. Thanks for your help.    -Tom